# How to convert multiple chars to decimal value?

Tags: c++, char, decimal

I'm trying to do the following:
I have a vector of chars that looks like: { '3' '2' 'a' '4' '4' 'a' '9' }.

('a' is just a place holder I've added to my vector to denote where one value ends and the other begins)

**I can't figure out how to make the chars 3 and 2 convert to the actual decimal value 32 and so on for 44 (9 is not hard.)**

Now before you all go and rate this as duplicate or "we won't do your homework" comments start showing up, I want you to know that I've omitted all the other steps I've **successfully** completed to save your and my time. I know atoi exists in C++ but we're not allowed to use them (along with any find_first_of or any sort of library functions). I believe ascii can do the job but just can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Because that was the homework. '3' - '0' gives the value of '3'. The rest is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: How about you try to figure something out, then if it doesn't work, post what you have?

Comment: @RichardPennington: Typo: `'3' - '0'` gives `3`, not `'3'`.

Comment: @NateEldredge Right. Mia culpa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intuitive leap you're missing is that a char is just a number you're using to encode a symbol of some kind, so it has a value.  Figure out the value of the numbers 0-9, and you can use that to translate the value of type char into a value of type int.  (Richard's example above is one way of doing that, for example.)

And then you have the digits of your number, and just have to derive the number from them.

Answer (score 0):

The character `3` in ASCII is 51 in decimal. `0->9` in ascii is `48-57` in decimal. So to get back the actual number, you just need to substract 48 from every `char c` you have.

```
char c = '3';
printf("%d\n",c-48);
```

If you want to concatenate the characters, you can look at [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace all occurrences of `'a'` to `' '`.
2. Split string with `std::istringstream`.
3. For each element call `std::stoi()` function.

Code example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> convert(const std::vector<char> & a) {
  std::string s(a.begin(), a.end());
  std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'a', ' ');
  std::vector<int> result;
  std::istringstream iss(s);
  std::string number;
  while (iss >> number) {
    result.push_back(stoi(number));
  }
  return result;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<char> a = {'3', '2', 'a', '4', '4', 'a', '9', '2'};
  std::vector<int> result = convert(a);
  for (int elem : result) {
    std::cout << elem << " ";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
32 44 92
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the hint: In decimal number system, as you go from right to left of  digits. It gets multiplied by 10.

For example {3, 2} can be converted like this:

```
x = 0;
```

1st iteration:

```
x = x * 10 + 3 // 3
```

2nd iteration:

```
x = x * 10 + 2 // 32
```